# How to update a same file to a destination folder which has different directory structure?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rsync, cp

Suppose I have folder structure:

```
folder: a.text

folder_2: folder_3: a.text
```

How I can sync this file without mentioning the full destination path?

I have tried

```
rsync -hvrPt folder/* folder_2
```

but it creates a new file under `folder_2`, instead I just want to update the `a.text` from `folder` to `folder_2` without mentioning the full destination path.

I have tried

```
rsync --update
```

also but it didn't work.

Could anybody help me with this?

Comment: Not `rsync` but GNU `cp(1)` has the `-u` flag, just my two cents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want `rsync` to update every found instance of the file. It won't do that. If you have just one file to update everywhere found in the target, you could try:

```
find folder_2 -name a.text -exec rsync -hvPt folder/a.text {} \; # no need for -r
```

I am not sure what you are doing with `-h`, unless you have really have hard links. It makes me think you are trying to update links versus files. Unless you have a good use case, you should probably use soft links (`ln -s`) as they can span file systems.